# How to do a top to position transition animation in CSS and vice versa

Tags: html, css, input, css-animations

I'm trying to add some flare to my game's home menu page and I'm trying to figure out how to make the big multicolored title in the middle come in from the top of the screen and end up where it is right now and the opposite for the button and input box.

[image]

The only animation I currently have is the gradient image background for the text.

```css
#outer {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-family: coconbold;
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 20px black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#inner {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: coconbold;
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 7rem;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 40, 40, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 121, 4, 1) 27%, rgba(252, 241, 73, 1) 40%, rgba(82, 252, 73, 1) 50%, rgba(73, 197, 252, 1) 60%, rgba(106, 53, 255, 1) 73%, rgba(150, 0, 214, 1) 85%);
  background-size: 200%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: anim 4s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}

#nickname {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px 0 9px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30%;
  height: 8%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 1px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  caret-color: grey;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

#spawnif {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
}

#spawnifin {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#playbtnin {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
}

#playbtnot {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(180, 179, 255);
  border-color: rgb(110, 107, 255);
  background-size: 500px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
}

#playbtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(161, 171, 255);
  border-color: rgb(103, 101, 255);
}
```

```html
<h1 id='outer'>rainboz.io</h1>
<h1 id='inner'>rainboz.io</h1>

<div>
  <form align="center">
    <label id='spawnif'>this is the story of...</label>
    <label id='spawnifin'>this is the story of...</label>
    <input type='text' spellcheck='false' maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" id='nickname' placeholder="Nickname">
    <button id='playbtnot'>Play</button>
    <button id='playbtnin'>Play</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

The border I'm doing on all the text requires double everything so that's why there's so much CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can do this by changing the html structure of your app a tiny bit.

You can have one container that's positioned absolutely with top and left values of 15% and 50%. The H1 elements inside this div will have position absolute(so they overlap), but left and top values would not be specified.

Then you can have the container animate by defining a new animation with @keyframes and specifying the top property of the container to go from -30% (or whatever) to 15%.

Here's a fiddle that does that.
https://jsfiddle.net/d58t2bau/

```
    <div class='ctr'>
  <h1 id='outer'>rainboz.io</h1>
  <h1 id='inner'>rainboz.io</h1>
</div>


<div>
  <form align="center">
    <label id='spawnif'>this is the story of...</label>
    <label id='spawnifin'>this is the story of...</label>
    <input type='text' spellcheck='false' maxlength="20" autocomplete="off" id='nickname' placeholder="Nickname">
    <button id='playbtnot'>Play</button>
    <button id='playbtnin'>Play</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  color: black;
  font-size: 7rem;
  font-family: coconbold;
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 20px black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#inner {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: coconbold;
  font-weight: 100;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 7rem;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 40, 40, 1) 15%, rgba(255, 121, 4, 1) 27%, rgba(252, 241, 73, 1) 40%, rgba(82, 252, 73, 1) 50%, rgba(73, 197, 252, 1) 60%, rgba(106, 53, 255, 1) 73%, rgba(150, 0, 214, 1) 85%);
  background-size: 200%;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  animation: anim 4s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes anim {
  from {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}

#nickname {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 40%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 3px 10px 0 9px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 30%;
  height: 8%;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 1px;
  border-color: lightgrey;
  background-color: rgb(247, 247, 247);
  border-width: 1px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  border-style: solid;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  caret-color: grey;
}

input::placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}

#spawnif {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: black;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
}

#spawnifin {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  top: 36%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: rgb(245, 244, 244);
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

#playbtnin {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: white;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
}

#playbtnot {
  box-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 90px;
  width: 215px;
  height: 50px;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  font-size: 35px;
  font-family: coconbold;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(180, 179, 255);
  border-color: rgb(110, 107, 255);
  background-size: 500px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 6px black;
}

#playbtn:hover {
  background-color: rgb(161, 171, 255);
  border-color: rgb(103, 101, 255);
}

.ctr {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  left: 50%;
  animation-name: float-in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@keyframes float-in {
  from {
    top: -50%;
  }
  to {
    top: 15%;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly for the title but I'm also trying to get the input box, the label, and the button to come up from the bottom of the screen. I tried copying what you did the title but with different 'from' and 'too' values but when I did it messed up the positioning and sizing of the input box a label I'm assuming I have to do an animation for each one of the elements to fix this but I'm not sure.

Comment: Yes, you can do similar animation for all the other elements. I've made a fiddle doing that. https://jsfiddle.net/x0jh3m18/ You can play around with the values and the animation time and try other animation properties too.

Comment: Thank's a lot man worked great! Now I can start making my actual game, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Please be sure to vote and select the answer as selected correct if that worked for you